# How to match a specific sentence with Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm new to Regex and I couldn't cope with matching this sort of sentence: `Band Name @Venue 30 450`, where the digits at the end represent price and quantity.

```
string input = "Band Name @City 25 3500";
Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"^[A-Za-z]+\s+[A-Za-z]+\s+[\d+]+\s+[\d+]$");
if (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Success!");
}
```

Comment: Doesn't your regular expression need to include the `@` symbol?

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: "(Band) ([A-Za-z ]+) (@[A-Za-z ]+) (\d+) (\d+)" this one will leverage groups it would be easier to extract data later. Could you try it?

Comment: This worked, but I also need the Band part to be flexible as well

Comment: @Shrexpecial what kind of flexibility? Now it can contains more than one word... you can tweak that part if you need depends on the conditions.

Comment: I switched it a bit and it worked out. Thanks

Comment: @Shrexpecial could I post it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Regex` and leverage usage of named groups. This will make easier to extract data later if you need them. Example is:

```
string pattern = @"(Band) (?<Band>[A-Za-z ]+) (?<City>@[A-Za-z ]+) (?<Price>\d+) (?<Quantity>\d+)";
string input = "Band Name @City 25 3500";

Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["Band"].Value);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["City"].Value.TrimStart('@'));
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["Price"].Value);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["Quantity"].Value);
```

If you looked at the pattern there are few `regex` groups which are named `?<GroupName>`. It is just a basic example which can be tweaked as well to fulfill you actual needs.

Comment: Yea, that's exactly what I did

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very old and elaborated way : **1st way**

```
string re1=".*?";   // Here the part before @
  string re2="(@)"; // Any Single Character 1
  string re3="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))";   // Word 1, here city
  string re4="(\\s+)";  // White Space 1
  string re5="(\\d+)";  // Integer Number 1, here 25
  string re6="(\\s+)";  // White Space 2
  string re7="(\\d+)";  // Integer Number 2, here 3500

      Regex r = new Regex(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.Singleline);
      Match m = r.Match(txt);
      if (m.Success)
      {
            String c1=m.Groups[1].ToString();
            String word1=m.Groups[2].ToString();
            String ws1=m.Groups[3].ToString();
            String int1=m.Groups[4].ToString();
            String ws2=m.Groups[5].ToString();
            String int2=m.Groups[6].ToString();
            Console.Write("("+c1.ToString()+")"+"("+word1.ToString()+")"+"("+ws1.ToString()+")"+"("+int1.ToString()+")"+"("+ws2.ToString()+")"+"("+int2.ToString()+")"+"\n");
      }
```

**In the above way you can store the specific values at a time**. Like in your group[6] there is 3500 or what value in this format.

you can create your own regex here : [Regex](https://txt2re.com/)

And in a short, others given answers are right. **2nd way**
just create the regex with

```
"([A-Za-z ]+) ([A-Za-z ]+) @([A-Za-z ]+) (\d+) (\d+)"
```

And match with any string format. you can create you won regex and test here: [Regex Tester](https://regexr.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

```
[A-Za-z ]+ [A-Za-z ]+ @[A-Za-z ]+ \d+ \d+
```

[Can test it here.](https://regex101.com/r/s2U2pS/1)

With your code it'd be:

```
string input = "Band Name @City 25 3500";
Match m = Regex.Match(input, "[A-Za-z ]+ [A-Za-z ]+ @[A-Za-z ]+ \d+ \d+");
if (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Success!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the answer to what I was trying to do:

```
string input = "Band Name @Location 25 3500";
Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"([A-Za-z ]+) (@[A-Za-z ]+) (\d+) (\d+)");
if (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Success!");
}
```

Comment: You should generally mark existing answers as the correct answer (if given), instead of reposting it yourself.

Comment: @Nicholas that was my actual question in the comment :). I will post anyway improved one :)

Comment: @Lepijohnny you answered first, so if you post an answer it should be the accepted one.